No module named pylsp.plugins.rope_rename
I use nvim with packer but after installation of pylsp with Mason, I have this error:
Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/client.lua:588: RPC[Error] code_name = InvalidParams, message = "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pylsp.plugins.rope_rename'" data = {                                                                                                                                                  
traceback = { "  File \"/home/wiskani/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pylsp_jsonrpc/endpoint.py\", line 117, in consume\n    self._handle_request(message['id'], message['method'], message.get('params'))\n", '  File "/home/wiskani/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pylsp_jsonrpc/endpoint.py", line 197, in _handle_request\n    handler_result = handler(params)\n                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n', '  File "/home/wiskani/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pylsp_jsonrpc/dispatchers.py", line 25, in handler\n    return method(**(params or {}))\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n', '  File "/home/wiskani/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pylsp/python_lsp.py", line 326, in m_initialize\n    self.config = config.Config(\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n', '  File "/home/wiskani/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pylsp/config/config.py", line 89, in __init__\n self._pm.load_setuptools_entrypoints(PYLSP)\n', '  File "/home/wiskani/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 421, in load_setuptools_entrypoints\n    plugin = ep.load()\n             ^^^^^^^^^\n', "  File \"/home/wiskani/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py\", line 189, in load\n    module = import_module(match.group('module'))\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n", '  File "/home/wiskanianaconda3/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n', '  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import\n', '  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load\n', '  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n' }                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                           
stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                                            
     [C]: in function 'assert'                                                                                                                                                           
     /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/client.lua:588: in function ''                                                                                                                  
     vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0> 

He tried reinstalling pylsp, installing rope manually, but it doesn't work.

I answered you on Reddit, but in case someone has the same problem and finds this post instead. To solve the problem you have to create a rope_rename.py file (it can be an empty one) in the error location.
In your case:
/home/wiskani/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pylsp/

If you are using Linux, you can just:
touch <path>/rope_rename.py

and it will work fine.
